# Finding the heaviest path of an undirected graph

Tags: c++, graph, breadth-first-search, dijkstra

I am trying to solve a particular problem but i cannot find any suitable solution.
I'll explain ... I have a graph where each node has a numeric value.
Starting from a node of my choice, I have to find the path where the sum of the node values is the heaviest.
The peculiarity of this problem, however, is that I can only cross the same bridge once BUT it is possible to pass several times on the same node.

to be even more precise, if I have a graph of this type

[image]

Starting from the node 1, the solution I should get would be this :
1->2->0->1->4 with a total weight of 23.

I tried to apply known algorithms such as Dijkstra or Prime but I don't think they are the right solution.
I couldn't find much on the internet. Is anyone able to provide me with any explanation or suggestions?
Could thinking about coloring the arches and not the knots lead me to a solution in your opinion?
A thousand thanks

Comment: This question doesn't seem significantly different from [the closed question that you deleted a day ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69830437/maximum-wheight-path-in-graph).

Comment: Find all the paths and select the heaviest one.

Comment: @c0der so do you also think that the only solution to the problem is to apply backtracking to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using a dfs variant like this:

```
int dfs(vector<vector<int> >& g,
        int* cost, int u, int pre){
    vis[u] = true;
    dp[u] = cost[u];
    bool check = 1;
    int cur = cost[u];
    for (auto& x : g[u]) {
        if (vis[x] && x != pre) {
            check = 0;
        }
        else if (!vis[x]) {
            check &= dfs(g, cost, x, u);
            cur = max(cur, cost[u] + dp[x]);
        }
    }
    dp[u] = cur;
    if (!check) {
        canTake += cost[u];
        path.push_back(u);
    }
    else {
        best = max(best, dp[u]);
        last_node = u;
    }
    return check;
}
```